# angular ui bootstrap ng-repeat tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I use ng-repeat in angular bootstrap  ?

```
  // styling does not work
  <uib-tabset active="activePill" vertical="true" type="pills">
    <span ng-repeat="tab in tabs track by $index">
      <uib-tab index="$index" heading="{{ tab.title }}">{{ tab.content }}</uib-tab>
    </span>
  </uib-tabset>
```

What am I missing? where should the ng-repeat go to preserve styling?

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QjHCxa0usskvfW7582Qr?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

use index="{{$index}}" instead of index="$index". See this

```
<uib-tabset active="activePill" vertical="true" type="pills">
    <span ng-repeat="tab in tabs track by $index">
      <uib-tab index="{{$index}}" heading="{{ tab.title }}">{{ tab.content }}</uib-tab>
    </span>
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: `{{$index}}` didn't work. Getting `Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{$index}}] starting at [{$index}}]` error